# InnoDB - How to get top locked tables and rows which are locked

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I was searching for a tool OR query which can give me top locked tables and which particular row is locked, Is it possible to get ?

Answer (score 2):

Just search for 'lock'

```
mysql> pager grep -C 3 -i lock
PAGER set to 'grep -C 3 -i lock'
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
... results ...
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> \n
PAGER set to stdout
mysql>
```